# Get value from anonymous function TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Angular project and I use the Signalr inside it.
But when I get the connectionId , I can print it.
But I can't assign it in the global variable. This is my code:

```
   connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:8178/notifyHub").build();
    connection.start().then(function () {
      connection.invoke("GetConnectionId").then(function (connectionId) {
       console.log(connectionId);
       // var temp=connectionId
      })
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: declare outside typescript  class  `var temp=""`  or inside typescript constructor  `var temp:string = ""; ` and then assign  inside typescript class.

Comment: @jitender  exactly

Comment: The problem is the scope of your function. As per @jitender's answer, fat arrow notation will allow the use of the correct scope, unless you implicitly want block level scope.

Comment: @mohammadalmasi accepted ans is not the right way to solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the same using the following :

```
temp;   
let self = this;
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:8178/notifyHub").build();
connection.start().then(function () {
  connection.invoke("GetConnectionId").then(function (connectionId) {
    console.log(connectionId);
    self.temp = connectionId;
  })
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

or the better solution is to use use [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

```
temp;
connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:8178/notifyHub").build();
connection.start().then(() => {
  connection.invoke("GetConnectionId").then((connectionId) => {
    console.log(connectionId);
    this.temp = connectionId;
  })
}).catch(err => console.error(err)
```

Comment: any reason behind not using `arrow` function and performing extra steps to active the same thing?

Comment: @jitender you are right using arrow functions is better , i have nothing against it though :)

Comment: you can update your answer to use arrow function so later if someone else come here with same problem then OP should goes to right direction

Comment: @jitender   i have updated the answer as you requested

Answer (score 2):

instead of `function` use [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like

```
connection = new 

   signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:8178/notifyHub").build();
    connection.start().then(()=> {
      connection.invoke("GetConnectionId").then((connectionId)=> {
       console.log(connectionId);
       // here you will be able to access this
      })
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: @jitender Why this way the first value is always undefined??

Comment: first value means?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
connectionId: any;

connection = new 
   signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:8178/notifyHub").build();
   connection.start().then(function () {
   connection.invoke("GetConnectionId").then(function (connectionId) {
   console.log(connectionId);

    this.connectionId = connectionId 

  })
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```